# .htaccess replace "/" with "_"

Tags: regex, .htaccess

This is my current htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # turn on rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine on

    # if request is a directory, make sure it ends with a slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*/[^/]+)$ $1/

    # if not rewritten before, AND requested file is wikka.php
    # turn request into a query for a default (unspecified) page
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !wakka=
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} wikka.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wikka.php?wakka= [QSA,L]

    # if not rewritten before, AND requested file is a page name
    # turn request into a query for that page name for wikka.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wikka.php?wakka=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

My current url structure is

```
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page_Example_Test
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page_Example_Test/edit
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page_Example_Test/edit?id=1
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page_Example_Test/history
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page_Number_Room
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page_Number_Room/edit
```

How Is it possible to access them like this

```
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page/Example/Test
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page/Example/Test/edit
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page/Example/Test/edit?id=1
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page/Example/Test/history
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page/Number/Room
www.domain.com/site/pool/Page/Number/Room/edit
```

having the htaccess change only those "/" for "_"
There is only /history and /edit finishing the url name nothing more, the normal is without /edit or /history.

Comment: Is everything lowercase except the page name?

Comment: You want us to write regex for you?

Comment: It can be yes, only page name have the first capital leter.

Comment: And are there always three pieces in the page name?

Comment: is it possible ? I've tried with regex's but no luck still, some guidelines would be very much appreciated. If no help I'll continue to search for a solution like I've been doing for a few days now...

Comment: @aliteralmind - there can be from 1 to 5 pieces.

Answer (score 1):

If there are between one and five pieces in the page name, such as

```
Page
Page/Page
Page/Page/Page
Page/Page/Page/Page
Page/Page/Page/Page/Page
```

and every element starts with a capital letter *and every other part of the url is only lowercase*, then you can accomplish this with four replacements (the one-piece-only one needs no replacement). For example, for three pieces:

- Find what: `([A-Z][a-z]+)\/([A-Z][a-z]+)\/([A-Z][a-z]+)(\/)?`
- Replace with: `$1_$2_$3$4`

You can try it [here](http://regex101.com/r/xN0hS7) (although I don't understand why it's only replacing with spaces in every line but the last).

Notes:

- Each part `(...)` is [captured](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127)
- The final slash `\/?` is [optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17400486), and is the slash before the potential "edit" or "history".
- In some regex flavors, you don't need to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078) the slash `/`, but it's safer to do so: `\/`.
- Each `$[number]` is a [capture group reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127)
- WARNING! These replacements must be done from longest to shortest: five pieces, then four, then three, then two. Otherwise, you'll seriously mess things up.

---

All the links in this answer come from the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496). Please consider bookmarking it for future reference. In particular, see the list of online regex testers in the bottom section, so you can try things out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in `/site/pool/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/pool/

RewriteRule "^(Page)/([^/]+)/([^/]+/.*)$" /$1/$2_$3 [L]
RewriteRule "^(Page)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$" /$1/$2_$3 [L]
```