# PHP replace a dynamic string with blank

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have this img tag

```
<img src="../img/tmp/pack_mini_5753_.jpg?time=1464793546" alt="" class="imgm img-thumbnail">
```

I would like to delete the string `?time=1464793546`. I have the time a dynamic variable so `1464793546` will change dependent on time.

I tried this

```
 $image_tag = ImageManager::thumbnail($path_to_image, 'pack_mini_'.$pack_item->id.'_'.$this->context->shop->id.'.jpg', 120);
                        var_dump($image_tag);
 $pattern = '/(\w+)?time=(\d+)/i';
 $replacement = '${1}';
 $pack_items[$i]['image'] =preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $image_tag);
 var_dump($pack_items[$i]['image']);exit;
```

`$image_tag` returns the img tag

```
<img src="../img/tmp/pack_mini_5753_.jpg?time=1464793546" alt="" class="imgm img-thumbnail">
```

Var_dump return null.

Comment: $pattern = '/\?time=(\d+)/i' escape `?`

Comment: [`?` has a special meaning in regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400048/how-does-the-make-a-quantifier-lazy-in-regex/17400486#17400486). Escape it `\?` or nullify its meaning by putting it in a character class `[?]`.

Comment: Thank you it works, i can accept it as a valid answer

Comment: You might want to use a character class, you won't need to escape and can include the `&` incase the parameter isn't first. `[?&]time=(\d+)`

Comment: You saved my day tcpdf had problem reading images with time parameter (in Prestashop)

Comment: @chris85 I've written the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape the question mark which has special meaning in regex. Just escape it:

```
$pattern = '/\?time=(\d+)/i';
```