# Validation of Email in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I don't know why the regex patterns was not working ! I couldn't find any error ! But when i run this with wrong input it just skips the pattern test line and moves to the next page !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Validation</title>
    <script>
        function validate()
        {
            var email=document.myform.email.value;
            var pass=document.myform.pass.value;
            var phno=document.myform.phno.value;
            if(email!="" && pass!="" && phno!="")
            {
                var emailcheck=/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
                var passcheck=/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,10}/;  
                var phonecheck=/^[0-9]{10}+$/;
                var result1=emailcheck.test(email);
                var result2=passcheck.test(pass);
                var result3=phonecheck.test(phno);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Validation failed");
                return false;
            }
            if(result1 && result2 && result3)
            {
                alert("Validation Successful");
                //return true;
            }
            else
            {
                    alert("Validation Failed");
                    document.write("email should be as (xxx@gmail.com)"+"<br/>"+"password should be as (pass123)"+"<br/>"+"phone should be as (98659-57575)"+"<br/>");
                    return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="myform" action="number.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
    Email:<input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
    Password:<input type="text" name="pass"/> <br/>
    Phone:<input type="text" name="phno"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the alert validation failed, if I give any input that mismatch the pattern.

Comment: 1) When you say "it just skips the pattern test line", what do you mean? Why do you think that?
2) What are some example input values that did not work?

Comment: If you check browser console when your page loads it returns:
'SyntaxError: nothing to repeat'
as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288181/javascript-regex-nothing-to-repeat-error, 'You need to double the backslashes used to escape the regular expression special characters'. as I see in your code you have multiple of this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has regex errors which leads to script fail. as `validate` script fails the `onsubmit` would not find `validate` function and so everything will ruined.
It is a good behavior to check your regex with online regex test sites like [this one](https://regexr.com/) 
I think if you change your regex part of code to this every thing will work correctly:

```js
var emailcheck=/^([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])+\\@([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])+\\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
var passcheck=/(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,10}/;  
var phonecheck=/^[0-9]{10}$/;
```

As you will notice I've changed every `/` with `//`, and also removed `+` in the last regex, as it was not valid.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Ahh! I got the output... Thank you mate!  and thanks for that link ! It may help me in the future :-)